# Chained Jquery Ajax Calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to retrieve some information about any given webpage (namely the  of the page and the  of the domain) and then make a jquery asynchronous POST with the retrieved information. Unfortunately, the javascript execution reaches the $.post(), but never makes the actual web request. Here is my code:

```
$.get('../embed', {u: url}, function(html) {
    alert('got "' + html + '"');
    $.post('/media/add', { story: storyid, caption: caption, type: 5, title: title, content: html, meta: meta }, function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
        var thumb = imageUrlFromMedia(obj);
        var clip = addToClipboard(obj.id, thumb || '/img/icons/embedly.png', obj.name);
    });
});
```

Is it even possible to make another ajax call in the success handler of $.get()? Has anyone here had any success with multiple chained HttpRequests before?

Comment: Can you confirm (with Firebug or similar) that no request is made? Otherwise, it could also be that the callback is just not working.

Comment: is this a typeo? "ty  pe: 5"   if not. that's your problem.  you should probably put your story, caption, type, title inside qoutes. it's not required, but it's a good habit incase you accidently have a property that is a reserved word.

Comment: Using Firebug, I can see that the GET request is made, and the alert in the GET's callback fires, but the POST request is never made and its callback never fires.

@Patricia: sorry, apparently I let a few spaces slip in when I copied the code to SO, I fixed it.

Comment: alright then, where are storyid and all those being populated?  
try building your data outside of the post, i find it makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.ajax to find errors in the XML HTTP requests or JSON parsing (may not work for JSON parsing unfortunately).  That should still display as text even if it fails to parse.  Anyways, to get failure messages refactor as so

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../embed',
  data: {u: url},
  success: function(html){
    ..
     $.post
    ..
  },
  error: function(XMLHTTPRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
     //Danger Will Robinson
  }
});
```

If you don't see a second request, this is the request that is failing.  If you still don't find an error, try doing the same with the $.post.  You should consider refactoring $.post to $.ajax.  By the way, parseJSON is automatic if you use $.getJSON instead of $.post.  This is akin to dataType: 'json' within $.ajax.